# Focus view on selected layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts, zoom

While working on a huge workspace I need Photoshop to focus the current view on the object / layer I selected, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found when searching in [this Adobe forum thread](https://forums.adobe.com/message/2581340#2581340), it's not possible. [Even in Illustrator](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/652788), you need a script or plugin to zoom in to a selected object.

Comment: The answer probably won't change, but I thought I'd point out the adobe forum post is about Illustrator and didn't seem to have any info about Photoshop.

Comment: @Joonas thanks for pointing out, I added the correct links

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left click</kbd> on a layer in the *Layers* panel to focus on it. This focuses the layer and zooms in on it.